# Call Function with Reference &

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, function-call

I solved the task with pointers. But i want to ask if its posible to call the function with & reference.
I think that would be easier to understand.

```
    void sortieren(cBruch* a, int anzahl)
    {


        for (int n = anzahl; n > 1; n--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
           {

                if (*(a + i) > * (a + i + 1))
                {
                    (a + i)->tausch((a + i), (a + i + 1));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `cBruch*` seems to be an array so references _**may not**_ be a neat solution in this case.

Comment: So if im working with arrays i should use pointers and if i need one single i can use it as reference? 

Im learning coding at college. So what is the most common use when im coding a real project?

Comment: You can change the function signature to be `void sortieren(cBruch& a, int anzahl)` then replace `a` in the old function core to be the address of `a` in the new function. but this isn't elegant alternative at all.

Comment: You're right, as a general rule of thumb _**use pointers**_ as function parameters when you expect an array. _**use references**_ when you are passing a single object. Don't worry about it to much; the more you practice, the more intuitive the choices become.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your usage of `a`, it seems to be a pointer to an array of `cBruch` objects. If you are required to use such an array, you'll have to keep the argument as a pointer. However, you can change how it's used in the function.

```
void sortieren(cBruch* a, int anzahl)
{
   for (int n = anzahl; n > 1; n--)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
      {
         if ( a[i] > a[i + 1])
         {
            a[i].tausch((a + i), (a + i + 1));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you change `cBrunch::tausch` to accept `cBruch&` instead of `cBruch*`, you can change the call to that function as:

```
a[i].tausch(a[i], a[i + 1]);
```

Comment: yea thank you. Worked fine. This looks much better than my way. I dont like this amount of brackets. Its confusing me a bit. But its how we are learning coding. 

Which style is the most common usage in real codes?

Comment: Still technically using a pointer, even though it's using syntax like an array.

Comment: @SefaSimsek, use references wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have function parameter pointer `a`:

```
void sortieren(cBruch* a, int anzahl)
```

which is dereferenced as an array:

```
if (*(a + i) > * (a + i + 1))
```

so, no, `a` can't be changed into a reference of any kind.